not Showing cityname and temperature
I am developing a weather application in Flutter, but unfortunately, I have encountered these bugs.unfortunately in home.dart _weather is null andIt does not show this is api_model.dart flie
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Weather {
  final String? cityName;
  final double? temp;
  final List<WeatherData>? weatherdesc;
  final double? humidity;

  Weather({
    required this.cityName,
    required this.temp,
    required this.weatherdesc,
    required this.humidity,
  });

  factory Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Weather(
      cityName: json['name'],
      temp: (json['main']['temp'] as num).toDouble(),
      weatherdesc: (json['weather'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => WeatherData.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList(),
      humidity: (json['main']['humidity'] as num).toDouble(),
    );
  }
}

@immutable
class WeatherData {
  final int? id;
  final String? main;
  final String? description;
  final String icon;

  WeatherData({
    required this.id,
    required this.main,
    required this.description,
    required this.icon,
  });

  factory WeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return WeatherData(
      id: json['id'],
      main: json['main'],
      description: json['description'],
      icon: json['icon'],
    );
  }
}

and this is weather_services file
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:weather_app/model/api_model.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

final logger = Logger();

class WeatherServices {
  final String apiKey;

  WeatherServices(this.apiKey);

  Future<String> getCurrentCity() async {
    logger.d('Checking location permission');
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        logger.e("Location permission denied");
        throw Exception("Location permission denied");
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      logger.e("Location permission denied forever");
      throw Exception("Location permission denied forever");
    }

    logger.d('Getting current position');
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    logger.d('Current position: ${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}');

    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks =
          await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      logger.d('Placemarks length: ${placemarks.length}');

      if (placemarks.isNotEmpty) {
        String? city = placemarks[0].locality;
        logger.d('City found: $city');
        return city ?? "Unknown location";
      } else {
        logger.e('No placemarks found');
        throw Exception("No placemarks found");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e('Geocoding Error: $e');
      throw Exception("Geocoding Error: $e");
    }
  }

  Future<Weather> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    final url =
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather&q=$cityName&appid=$apiKey&units=metric';
    logger.d('Fetching weather data from: $url');
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      logger.d('Weather data fetched successfully');
      logger.d("cityName is {$Weather.cityName}");
      return Weather.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      logger.e('Failed to load weather data: ${response.statusCode}');
      throw Exception('Failed to load weather data');
    }
  }
}

and finally this is home file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/model/api_model.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/services/weather_service.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final _weatherService = WeatherServices("api-key");
  Weather? _weather;

  final logger = Logger();

  Future<void> _fetchWeather() async {
    logger.d("Fetching weather...");
    try {
      final cityName = await _weatherService.getCurrentCity();
      logger.d('City: $cityName');

      final weather = await _weatherService.getWeather(cityName);
      setState(() {
        _weather = weather;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e("Failed to fetch weather");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchWeather();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    "assets/images/background.png",
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        ),
        if (_weather != null)
          Positioned(
            top: 120,
            left: 130,
            child: Text(
              _weather!.cityName ?? "null",
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        if (_weather != null)
          Positioned(
            top: 160,
            left: 130,
            child: Text(
              '${_weather?.temp?.round() ?? "N/A"}°C',
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        Positioned(
          top: 130,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Container(
            width: width / 1.3,
            height: height / 1.3,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(
                "assets/images/House.png",
              ),
            )),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: height / 2.5,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xFF2E335A),
                      Color(0xFF48319D),
                    ]),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(55),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(55),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

where is my problem? thanks for help!
i want to help me to show cityname and temperature

The error "cityName is empty" is expected in this code snippet logger.d("cityName is {$Weather.cityName}"); because you're trying to access the 'cityName' property of the 'Weather' object before it's even been created.
To see what comes from the API and where it comes from, you should check the content of the incoming response with the code print("Response : $response"); after this code final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
